# Dynamic consumption of messages from a kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I need to consume the messages from the topics that are created dynamically by the producer.
I have used the topic pattern approach in the consumer @KafkaListener(topicPattern = "topicname_.*"  for that and have also set the metadata.max.age.ms=3000.
But apparently unless and until i set the offset.auto.reset to earliest i am not able to achieve that.
In our requirement the offset.auto.reset has to be set to latest to avoid the duplication of the issue.

Any ideas on how to achieve the same?

Comment: `>has to be set to latest to avoid the duplication of the issue.` That is incorrect; `auto.offset.reset` only applies the first time a consumer with a particular `group.id` consumes from a partition. As soon as it commits an offset, in future, consumption will begin at that offset - unless the offset is expired because the consumer hasn't consumed for a week (by default).

Comment: I have created a consumer which consumes from the topics based on a pattern, I have set the offset.auto.reset to latest and have set the metadata.max.age.ms to 5 secs but the consumer is missing starting/first message always but consuming the message from there on. I am using Spring-kafka module.
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')
record_metadata = producer.send(topic, data)
and code for consumer is

Please suggest something to over come this problem or any configuration i have to include in my producer and consumer instances.

Comment: You must use `earliest` to get all the records in the new topic. Kafka is not really designed for your use case. 5 seconds for metadata age is rather aggressive.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking at top level, The design philosophy of Kafka doesn’t allow anything like this because adding topics at runtime causes hard rebalance on the brokers and hence it has to be avoided, But if we manage to restart the consumer groups every time a new topic is added to the list, We can gracefully avoid this hazard.

The most recent Spring-Kafka integration and its usage includes the annotation `@KafkaListener` which turns your POJO listener to a Kafka consumer by creating a KafkaListenerContainer using the container factory passed to it. This consumer listens to the topics hardcoded as a string array of topics, topic expressions, topic patterns etc. This limits our design to fetching these topics as keys through a Java DSL at max instead of directly hardcoding. However the keys are still hardcoded within an array passed as a parameter to `@KafkaListener`.

Example:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {“${kafka.topics.receipt.cancel.name}”}, containerFactory = “kafkaContainerFactory”)
```

Note: The value for annotation attribute KafkaListener.topics must be an array initializer, Therefore the hardcoding is mandatory.

Comment: I have not hardcoded it. I have it in the application.properties.
@KafkaListener(topicPattern = "${topic.prefix}" , the value topic.prefix has the pattern to be read.